# Djando CMS with USE_I18N = False

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-templates, django-cms

I have a Django-CMS project in a Russian language. I want to disable urls localization and language switcher. I can do it by settings `USE_I18N = False`. It works, but... Template translation became English, not Russian. My user has *ru* language and django settings looks like

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('ru')),
)
```

How to force my default language for toolbar and other templates?

Comment: Django==1.6.5, django-cms==3.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my bad undestanding of how Django localization works

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/#definitions

> The words “internationalization” and “localization” often cause
>   confusion; here’s a simplified definition:
>
> **internationalization** Preparing the software for localization. Usually
>   done by developers. 
>   **localization** Writing the translations and local
>   formats. Usually done by translators.

And warning about settings variable names

> Translation and formatting are controlled by USE_I18N and USE_L10N
>   settings respectively. However, both features involve
>   internationalization and localization. The names of the settings are
>   an unfortunate result of Django’s history.

So if you turn off i18n, you will have your web app not translated

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_I18N

> If this is set to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
>   to load the translation machinery.

To disable localized urls, edit your `urls.py` to use `django.conf.urls.patterns` instead of `django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns`, *Captain Obvious* said.

Answer (score -1):

remove the LanguageCookieMiddleware.